# Error when trying to retrieve Go Terms from GO ID in R/Bioconductor

Tags: r, bioconductor

I have a couple of GO IDs (sth like `GO:0000502`) and want to use the Bioconductor package `GO.db` to retrieve the name of the corresponding GO Term (which should be "proteasome complex" in this case).

In the past, the following worked for me:

```
library(GO.db)
library(org.Sc.sgd.db)
Term(get("GO:0000502", GOTERM))
```

However, after updating to R version 3.4.4 / Bioconductor 3.6 (and using `biocLite()` to update all packages), I get the following error:

```
Error in initialize(value, ...) : 
Argument "go_id" missing
```

I don't really want to downgrade again, if possible. Maybe there is a change in the package? I couldn't find out what goes wrong...